# How to customize AbstractCassandraConfiguration class?

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I am new to Spring framework.  I am working on a Spring Data Cassandra project where I want to set up a Cassandra keyspace and table programmatically.  Most of the examples I found on the Web require manual set up of them using cqlsh.

As a start, I create a spring starter project on STS4 with only the Cassandra dependency selected.  Here are the dependencies in my pom file:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Then I added my CassandraConfiguration class which extends the AbstractCassandraConfiguration class.  I fixed editor warning by implementing the only missing method getKeyspaceName().  Here is my added code.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "demo";
    }

}
```

But when I launch my spring boot app, it has the following error:

```
2019-04-18 14:54:24.588  INFO 38410 --- [           main] com.datastax.driver.core                 : DataStax Java driver 3.6.0 for Apache Cassandra
2019-04-18 14:54:24.590  INFO 38410 --- [           main] c.d.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility       : Detected Guava >= 19 in the classpath, using modern compatibility layer
2019-04-18 14:54:24.694  INFO 38410 --- [           main] com.datastax.driver.core.ClockFactory    : Using native clock to generate timestamps.
2019-04-18 14:54:24.880  INFO 38410 --- [           main] com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil       : Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
2019-04-18 14:54:24.909  WARN 38410 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/JmxReporter
2019-04-18 14:54:27.174  INFO 38410 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-04-18 14:54:27.182 ERROR 38410 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/JmxReporter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$76/1793436274.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:830) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.demo.CassandraDemoApplication.main(CassandraDemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/JmxReporter
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Metrics.<init>(Metrics.java:146) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1501) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:208) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:376) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:332) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.connect(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:89) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:82) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraSessionFactoryBean.java:59) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

So apparently besides the missing method, there are other things I need to add to my config class to make it work.  Can someone give me an idea what I am missing and how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

In Metrics 4, JMX reporting was moved to a separate module, `metrics-jmx`, and this causes that error - it's even described [in the documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/metrics/#metrics-4-compatibility). You can either add to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
  <artifactId>metrics-jmx</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or specify `withoutJMXReporting` when creating the `Cluster` object...

Comment: I am still seeing same error with the metrics dependency added.

Comment: Another possibility is that you didn’t assemble app properly, or conflict between dependencies

Comment: I think I am missing the bean for session, as said in the error below.  I wish someone can give me an example on how to add the session bean.  </br>  


Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/CassandraConfiguration.class]

Comment: You need to look to line “Caused by” - it’s main reason for exception...

Answer (score 0):

Or you can override and disable the metrics in your CassandraConfiguration so you don't need to add the metrics-jmx module

```
@Override
protected boolean getMetricsEnabled() { 
     return false; 
}
```